# Chart JS no funciona si no hasta que le doy click al label 2 veces

Tags: mysql, chart.js

Estoy tratando de generar una grafica basica con una consulta que ya funciona, pero cuando le doy click al boton para generar la grafica, esta queda vacia y solo carga cuando oprino el label 2 veces, después de eso queda perfecta, pero la idea es que funcione al momento de oprimir el boton

```
        $.post("views/ajax/reportes_ajax.php", { grafico }, function (dato) {
            let response = JSON.parse(dato)
            console.log(response)
    

            const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Producción de leche en litros',
                            backgroundColor: [
                                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                            ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        y: {
                            beginAtZero: false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }) 
             response.map(x => {
                myChart.data['labels'].push(x.fecha_registro)
                myChart.data['datasets'][0].data.push(x.cantidad)

            }) 
        })
```